# Block Same Domain Iframe Access To Parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent, parent-child, same-origin-policy

I have a website xyz.com with an iframe that loads xyz.com/usersubmittedpage.html inside the iframe.

How can i block the inner page from accessing the parent page. Same Origin Policy allows it to access everything in the parent. Is there another approach I could use to load this page without giving it access to the parent content while keeping it in the same domain.

Comment: why do you want to do that? Has this something to do with 3rd party content you cannot control?

Comment: Can you not serve the iframe on a different subdomain?

Comment: The page loaded in the iframe will contain user content that needs to allow javascript. I have access to all that data, but I was trying to avoid extensive parsing and removal, if there was a more secure and easier solution. If there is a php tool that exists to easily parse the content, that could be a solution, but i don't know of one and want to avoid extensive extra programming.

I can serve it on another subdomain, which seems might be the easiest/only solution. That seemed more of a workaround than a solution, but that may be what I have to do.

Comment: Everything else would be hack. Use another domain. Quick, simple and secure.

Answer (score 3):

Well...

There is the sandbox attribute to iframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox

[But it's only supported (reliably) in Chrome (as of this writing, 9/11/2012).](http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox)  (It will be supported/is supported elsewhere, but barely.)

Comment: 2017 update ... supported in all major browsers (except opera mini)